# Issue with calling a method from a VF controller class in a trigger?

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger

```
public class OpportunityDSForSFController {
public Opportunity opportunity {get; set;}
public OpportunityDSForSFController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){ 
        opportunity =  (Opportunity) controller.getRecord();
        setTemplateIdMap();
        setOpportunity();
        
    }
public PageReference inPerson(){ 
        System.debug('OpportunityDSForSFController :: Entered inPerson ::');
        Map<String, String> parameters = new Map<String, String>();
        parameters.put('SourceID', (String) opportunity.Id);
        return getDSPageRef(parameters);    
    }

private PageReference getDSPageRef(Map<String,String> parameters){
        String ref = '/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0';
        ref += '&SourceID=' + parameters.get('SourceID');
        ref += '&RC=' + parameters.get('RC');
        ref += '&RSL=' + parameters.get('RSL');
        ref += '&RSRO=' + parameters.get('RSRO');
        ref += '&RROS=' + parameters.get('RROS');
        ref += '&CCRM=' + parameters.get('CCRM');
        ref += '&CCTM=' + parameters.get('CCTM');
        ref += '&CCNM=' + parameters.get('CCNM');
        ref += '&CRCL=' + parameters.get('CRCL');
        ref += '&CRL=' + parameters.get('CRL');
        ref += '&OCO=' + parameters.get('OCO');
        ref += '&DST=' + parameters.get('DST');
        ref += '&LA=' + parameters.get('LA');
        ref += '&LF=' + parameters.get('LF');
        ref += '&CEM=' + parameters.get('CEM');
        ref += '&CES=' + parameters.get('CES');
        ref += '&STB=' + parameters.get('STB');
        ref += '&SSB=' + parameters.get('SSB');
        ref += '&SES=' + parameters.get('SES');
        ref += '&SEM=' + parameters.get('SEM');
        ref += '&SRS=' + parameters.get('SRS');
        ref += '&SCS=' + parameters.get('SCS');
        ref += '&RES=' + parameters.get('RES');
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(ref);
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;
    }
    
    }
```

My Trigger

```
for (Opportunity opportunity : Trigger.new) {
            ApexPages.StandardController controller = new ApexPages.standardController(opportunity);
            OpportunityDSForSFController dsForSfHandler = new OpportunityDSForSFController(controller);
            opportunity = (Opportunity) controller.getRecord();
            System.debug('OpportunityAfterUpdate :: opportunity :: '+opportunity);
            if(opportunity.StageName == 'Accepted'){
              dsForSfHandler.inPerson();  
            } 
}
```

However the method should send a document but it is not, I am unable to understand as why the method is not getting called here. Updated the code for better understanding

Comment: What kind of result do you expect? Method seems to be calling, it is just not doing anything

Comment: It should send a document through docusign.

Comment: Not sure why it is not doing anything

Comment: I think I know the reason, the method is calling a pagereference with parameters and I think Trigger does not support this. Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dsForSfHandler.inPerson();
```

All this does is get a reference to a page, and then throws that reference away. Even if the target Visualforce page had bad design like DML in its Action attribute, this would do nothing whatsoever.

It's important to remember that triggers do not have user interface sessions. You cannot render a Visualforce page in a trigger, because the `getContent*()` methods count as a callout. You can't invoke functionality that lives in the UI.

Any external work you need to do in a trigger or other "headless" Apex context, like a Queueable or a Batch job, must be done via API. A trigger should virtually never instantiate a Visualforce controller class.